# How to check if data attribute has value

Tags: jquery

How i can check with jquery if data attribute has certain value.
for example:

```
data-categories="first-value second-value third-value"
```

and i just want to check if it has `second-value`

:::::::::UPDATE QUESTION::::::::::::
I am creating a portfilio filter navigation here is the code.

```
    var $container = $('#container');
    var $categoryNavBar = $('.category-navbar');     
    var getCurrentCategory = function(){
          var filter = $categoryNavBar.find('li[class=select]').data('category');
          return filter;
    }

    $categoryNavBar.on('click', 'a', function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();

        var $this = jQuery(this);

        if($this.parent('li').hasClass('select')){
            return;
        }

        $this.parent('li').addClass('select').siblings('li').removeClass('select');

        var elem =  $container;
        var filter = $this.parent('li').data('category');

        if(filter == 'all'){
            elem.children('div').show().addClass('hb_box hb-brick').css({'top': 200, 'left': 200});
        }else{
            elem.children('div[data-category="'+filter+'"]').show().addClass('hb_box hb-brick').css({'top': 200, 'left': 200});
            elem.children('div').not('.hb_box[data-category="'+filter+'"]')
                        .removeClass("hb_box hb-brick")
                        .hide();

        }


    });
```

Comment: How did you attempt to do it? What was the result? Do you just want to check of do you what to select the element with the attribute and manipulate it further?

Comment: Use `.split()` to split it into an array, then `.indexOf()` to search the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) (`$("[attr*='foo']")`):

```
elem.children('div[data-category*="'+filter+'"]').show().addClass('hb_box hb-brick').css({'top': 200, 'left': 200});
elem.children('div').not('.hb_box[data-category*="'+filter+'"]')
                    .removeClass("hb_box hb-brick")
                    .hide();
```

Comment: I don't think the OP means the "second-value" is a string of exactly "second-value", it looks like a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

let's say `string = 'first-value second-value third-value`'

You could split the string at the " ", which will give you an array of all the values in your data attribute:

```
array = string.split(" ");
```

Then with some simple logic, you can find out if there is a second value

```
if array[1] != undefined {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store the data in the data attribute as an array, you can do your checks like so:

```js
var secVal = 'second-value';

if( $('div').data('categories').indexOf( secVal ) > -1 ) {
    alert( 'Has ' + secVal );
} else {
    alert( 'Does not have ' + secVal );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-categories="['first-value', 'second-value', 'third-value']"></div>
```